# Compare 2 lists and return index and value to a third list

Tags: python, list

```
answer_list = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
student_answers = ['a', 'c', 'b', 'd']
incorrect = []
```

I want to compare index 0 in list1 to index 0 in list2 and, if they are equal, move to compare index 1 in each list.

In this instance index 1 in list1 != index 1 in list 2 so I want to append index+1 and the incorrect student answer (in this case the letter c) to the empty list. This is what I tried - unsuccessfully.

```
def main():
    list1 = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
    list2 = ['a', 'c', 'b', 'd']
    incorrect = []

    for x in list1:
        for y in list2:
            if x != y:
                incorrect.append(y)

    print(incorrect)

main()
```

Comment: Could you give some *input/output* examples?

Comment: use [enumerate()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#enumerate)

Comment: Your code does not follow your algorithm as described. You want to loop over the _indices_ and compare list1 and list2 at each index, but your code is looping over the _values_ of one list, and for each value, comparing it to each value of the other list.

Answer (score 4):

Since you need to compare lists element-by-element, you also need to iterate over those list simultaneously. There is more than one way to do this, here are a few.

Built-in function [zip](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#zip) allows you to iterate over multiple iterable objects. This would be my method of choice because, in my opinion, it's the easiest and the most readable way to iterate over several sequences all at once.

```
for x,y in zip(list1, list2):
    if x != y:
        incorrect.append(y)
```

The other way would be to use method [enumerate](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#enumerate):

```
for pos, value in enumerate(list1):
    if value != list2[pos]:
        incorrect.append(list2[pos])
```

Enumerate takes care of keeping track of indexing for you, so you don't need to create a special counter just for that.

The third way is to iterate over lists using index. One way to do this is to write:

```
for pos range(len(list1)):
    if list1[pos] != list2[pos]:
        incorrect.append(list2[pos])
```

Notice how by using `enumerate` you can get index out-of-the-box.

All of those methods can also be written using list comprehensions, but in my opinion, this is more readable.

Answer (score 3):

You can use enumerate and list comprehension to check the index comparison.

```
answer_list = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
student_answers = ['a', 'c', 'b', 'd']

incorrect = [y for x,y in enumerate(answer_list) if y != student_answers[x]]
incorrect
['b', 'c']
```

If you want the indexes that don't match and the values:

```
incorrect = [[y,answer_list.index(y)] for x,y in enumerate(answer_list) if y != student_answers[x]]

[['b', 1], ['c', 2]]
```

In `x,y in enumerate(answer_list)`, the `x` is the index of the element and `y` is the element itself, so checking  `if y != student_answers[x]` is comparing the elements at the same index in both lists. If they don't match, the element `y` is added to our list.

Using a loop similar to your own:

```
def main():
    list1 = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
    list2 = ['a', 'c', 'b', 'd']
    incorrect = []    
    for x,y in enumerate(list1):
        if list2[x] != y:
            incorrect.append(y)    
    print(incorrect)
In [20]: main()
['b', 'c']
```

To get element and index:

```
def main():
    list1 = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
    list2 = ['a', 'c', 'b', 'd']
    incorrect = []    
    for x,y in enumerate(list1):
        if list2[x] != y:
            incorrect.append([y,list1.index(y)])    
    print(incorrect)
In [2]: main()
[['b', 1], ['c', 2]]
```